# Different Rubocop results based on local or CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circleci, rubocop

I just started using Rubocop in my Ruby on Rails project and created a git branch to refactor and get Rubocop up to speed with what I want. I finally have no offenses in when I run the command

```
$ rubocop
```

However, I tried to integrate Rubocop into my CircleCI builds and that is where I am having trouble. Here is the relevant part of my circle.yml file:

```
test:
  post:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```

The issue is, locally Rubocop says it is inspecting 68 files but on CircleCI it says it is inspecting 5624 files. Because of that it is not passing. What would cause me to get a different output when running locally versus on CircleCI?

Also, if I run:

```
bundle exec rubocop
```

locally I get the output I am expecting (68 files, all good).

Answer (score 5):

I figuring it out.

I'm not sure why, but for some reason on my local host it is ignoring the vendor file, but on CircleCI it was not so I added it to the .rubocop.yml file.

Comment: Some extra detail: CircleCI installs gems into the `vendor/` folder, which isn't what happens in a traditional `rbenv` setup. Adding `vendor/**/*` to the `Exclude` key under `AllCops` prevents all the gems from being scanned when you run `bundle exec rubocop`. Rubocop docs: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/configuration.md#includingexcluding-files

Comment: Useful command for debugging rubocop issues: `rubocop -d`  https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1652#issuecomment-74373641

Comment: ah, for me I was running `rubocop -a --config rubocop.yml` rather than `bundle exec rubocop -a --config rubocop.yml`, your question was my answer